# Looking for a left mouse button autoclick script, possibly for Powershell

Tags: powershell

Similar to hover click option in Ubuntu.  Thinking infinite while loop with a nested if else statement.  If mouse is moving, no click and sleep for 2 seconds, else mouse click left and sleep until mouse moves again. Needed for work environment, so Powershell would be best if its possible. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will move the cursor diagonally backwards & forwards every 2 seconds.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

do {
  $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
  $pos.X--; $pos.Y--; [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = $pos
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
  $pos = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
  $pos.X++; $pos.Y++; [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = $pos
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
}
while ($true)
```